# rewrite url www.xyz.com/index.php?id=xyz to www.xyz.com/xyz using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to include item details `details.php` if url has parameter `id=xyz`

rewrite

```
url www.example.com/index.php?id=xyz
```

to

```
www.example.com/xyz.html
```

using `htaccess`

htaccess i am using has

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad. We like for new users to try solving the problem, and to present that in the question. You'll find that the more effort you demonstrate, the more effort people will expend in assisting you.

Comment: You DO have `mod_rewrite` enabled, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?id=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?id=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+?)(?:\.html)?$ /index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for response, i applied this but it does not redirect and if if hit url lik
    www.example.com/xyz.html it gives 404 error

Comment: What happens when you enter: `www.example.com/xyz.html` URL?

Comment: yes .htaccess is enable and i gave 505 error and also other rules i apply works but am not getting what i want

Comment: Your rules are conflicting. How will you decide if `/foobar.html` will be handled by `index.php` or `section.php`?

Comment: oh . thanks . there is no section.php . . it meant to be index.php

Comment: ok where is this .htaccess located and where is index.php? Just comment out all rules and keep just the mine and then test with `www.example.com/xyz.html` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess to rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled (use `phpinfo()` or `apache_get_modules()` in PHP if available)

Answer (score 0):

Please try following configuration in your www.example.com/.htaccess file,
i just test it and work fun on my env.

```
//htaccess file content
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^(\w+).html$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```